# Why System.getProperty("home.dir") returns null

Tags: java

I cant figure out why System.getProperty("home.dir") is returning null instead of the current working directory.

I am using Eclipse Mars2.0 IDE on Ubuntu 16.04. I guess, this hardly matters which IDE I am using or the OS version.

```
package test;

public class testing {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("home.dir"));
    }

}
```

I am expecting to get a return for this code as something like /home/[user]/Workspace/test

Comment: How to remove the blue box with that text above: "This question already has answers here:" the answer is wrong, the user home directory is a different concept than a working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home.dir is not a java property as specified here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

If by working directory you mean the users working directory then user.home should work.

Example:

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Outputted:

```
C:\Users\User
```

If you mean the .jars working directory then I do not believe such a property exists.
Instead use:

```
    your_class.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

This will return a string specifying where the jar is situated currently.

Example:

```
    System.out.println(new File(**TestLighting.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()**));
```

(new File() is to get the correct formatting, it was /C:/...)

Outputted:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Java\Netbeans\Engine\build\test\classes
```

(This is the path of where the jar is being run from)

If home.dir is a system environment variable then you would use System.getenv()

Comment: I actually need the absolute path of the initialized application

Comment: As in where the jar you run is located? If so then then that is what I meant by  **.jars working directory**. If not then please clarify with an example

Comment: Thank you, I also added an example, I believe my second suggestion with 'your_class.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();' is the correct one that you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this workaround worked. Thank you.However, I cant find out why System.getProperty("home.dir") did not work on the first place.

Comment: Home.dir is not a system property. Look at the link I put there. It shows all system properties.

Comment: Ahh.. Thats it... I require that "user.dir" System property to work on. Had it confused with "user.home".  - Thank you so much...